# Unknown output in php

Tags: php, html, post

i am trying to create a checkbox form from values in an array in php to be submitted via POST. This is the code:

```
<?php 
$check = array('beiber' => 'dumb', 'john' => 'singer', 'michael' =>            'legend', 'lovato' => 'firestarter');
$t = 1;
$name = $t;
foreach($check as $x =>$y){
    $name = $t++;
    echo $name;
    echo ' <input type = "checkbox" name =' . $name . 'value =' . $x . '/>' . $x  . $sp . $y . '<br>';
}
?>
<input name = "submit" type = "submit" value = "submit" /><br>

<?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    print_r( $_POST);
}
?>
```

The output I get after clicking submit if all boxes are checked is:

```
Array ( [1value] => on [2value] => on [3value] => on [4value] => on [submit]   => submit )
```

My question is why are they having the value 'on' and how do i fix it. Thanks.

Comment: @john Conde, why was i down voted?

Comment: i assigned values to the checkboxes and thats what i want sent to POST

Comment: @brown.cn How should I know?

Comment: @john Conde If you really checked the code you would've seen it

Comment: @brown.cn I just edited your question. So I don't know why people downvoted you or care what you're asking. Although after reading the question and seeing your comments I am guessing it is because your question is due to a simple mistake that basic troubleshooting would have caught and your attitude is poor.

Comment: Dude. I don't know what your issue is. I don't see any big issue here. We r all just learning. And I really don't see how my attitude is poor, if possible enlighten me. And yeah, I'm a noob at this so if nothing else please try to have a little more patience with noobs like me. I do appreciate your help in clarifying. I actually never knew htmlspecialchars mattered that much. Please don't be pissed. My bad .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're outputting wrong html, change output line to:

```
echo '<input type="checkbox" name="' . htmlspecialchars($name) . '" value="' . htmlspecialchars($x) . '" />' . htmlspecialchars($x . $sp . $y) . '<br>';
```

Note:

1. quotes around attribute values
2. spaces between attribute names
3. htmlspecialchars to escape special symbols

Comment: yes. I guess thats it. Yours worked alright. I didnt think escaping the variables would matter. thank you.